# Usability Metrics for for Windows Remote Desktop Services

Tags: remote-desktop-services

I am trying to find out if there are ways to capture some metrics to measure the usability of a remote desktop services server (2008R2). Particularly, I am trying to record:

- How long it takes to logon users
- Time it takes to open applications
- If applications freezes
- etc.

Comment: In Remote App or they use RDP in full desktop ? I ask as the metric can lie for the second application to open if it open on the same server (printer are already mapped in example) or if it can be RemoteApp to multiple servers.

Comment: Mainly RDP full desktop. I'm a lot interested in measuring and monitoring the logon time, but also trying to gauge the "user experience" so if opening Word takes 1 minute, then I want to know. Just like we measure web app request response time basically, but in RDP context.

Comment: I found this, not tested yet, but wanted to note it for others: uberAgent (https://uberagent.com/)